# My if statement returns unexpected results, making random Sudoku with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I've been trying to make a program that creates Sudoku's randomly using Javascript. I've included both the code and pictures of that code in Atom to make it somewhat more readable.

Basically from line 16-20 I add 9 numbers to row, then shuffle them and store the result in newRow.

From line 25 onwards I start a loop that goes through all the past rows, which are stored in the array called 'actualRow'. So row gets shuffled into newRow, newRow is stored in actualRow. From the second newRow onwards I want to check whether there are any duplicate values. This is why I start loop1 and loop2. Loop1 to loop through all previous rows, and loop2 within that to loop through all the values.

The if statement is intended to catch duplicates, but doesn't ever evaluate to true, which it obviously should because there are always many duplicates.If it would be true, mistake = true, and thus I would not add that particular newRow to actualRow, but start the loop over until it does not encounter duplicates.

So really the problem lies in the if-statement in line 32. What am I missing here?

```js
  <script>
    var row = [];
    var newRow = [];
    var actualRow = [];
    var mistake;

function makeSudoku() {
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    newRow = [];
    mistake = false;

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      newRow.push( row.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * row.length) , 1) );
    }

    if ( j !== 0) { // no need to check for duplicates in first row

      loop1:
      for (var k = j-1; k > -1 ; k--) { // for every row that came before..
        loop2:
        for (var l = 0; l < 9; l++) { // for every value in that row..
          if ( actualRow[j-1][l] == newRow[l] ) { // issue here!!!
            mistake = true;
            console.log("duplicate row value");
          } else {
            console.log("Why does this if statement always evaluate to else?");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if ( mistake == false) {
      actualRow.push(newRow);
    } else if ( mistake == true) {
      j -= 1;
    } else {
    }
}

console.log(actualRow);
}

makeSudoku();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is in this line:

```
  newRow.push( row.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * row.length) , 1) );
```

This builds an array, but not an array of numbers, but an array of single-element arrays! Comparing those later will always yield false, and explains why you always get into the `else` part.

The cause is in how the `splice` method works. It returns an array, even if you only extract one element. The solution is, to "unwrap" the value from the array you get from `splice`:

```
  newRow.push( row.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * row.length) , 1)[0] );
```

Now it will work, but be aware that your algorithm is very inefficient. When generating the last row, it will need many attempts to get it right, because there is only ***one*** permutation that will be allowed in that last row. This makes your code iterate thousands of times trying to get it right with pure random shuffles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I see why they didn't compare right. And I realised my code isn't very efficient, but I'm seeing whether I can get the code to work. Perhaps when I get better at it will I let the sudoku sort of complete itself instead of randomly getting the right line as you point out. Thanks again!

Comment: I am surprised to see you unaccepted my answer more than half a year after having accepted it. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you check for a value in the array `actualRow` in line `32`, but the first time you write something to `actualRow` is in line `43`, so `actualRow` is an uninitialized array when you check it and it returns undefined behaviour. So, I think the solution would be to put values in `actualRow` before you check it.

regards,

tagelicht

Comment: Although I didn't consider this, I actually think it passes the whole if statement the first time around because j == 0 the first time over ( because the first row doesn't need to be checked for duplicates). So in a sense it will get to line 43 the first time it loops through, only the second time it loops will it get to line 32 but then there is already an array in there (the newRow) from the previous loop... Or is this not what you meant? Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by [*tagelicht*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39319158/2952875) is the first thing I thought of, too. But the actual problem is something simpler. When you compare the two values, they don't seem to have the same type (I'm not entirely sure just yet why this is the case). You can simply parse the integer of the objects using `parseInt()` (find the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)).This code works for me (only edited the code from line 22 onward):

```
for (var l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
  console.log('actualRow: ' + actualRow[j-1][l]);
  console.log('newRow: ' + newRow[l]);
  console.log(parseInt(actualRow[j-1][l]) == parseInt(newRow[l]));

  if ( parseInt(actualRow[j-1][l]) == parseInt(newRow[l]) ) {
    mistake = true;
    console.log("duplicate row value");
  } else {
    console.log("Why does this if statement always evaluate to else?");
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Also already pointed out by [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39319340/2952875) the problem is in line 23, with the `splice()` method. Since this method returns an array (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) fore more information), the comparison to an integer always fails. A better approach then my original solution above is to just   `push` the actual value into the `newRow` array in line 14 by adding a `[0]` after the `splice()` call:

```
newRow.push( row.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * row.length) , 1)[0] );
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me too. Somehow they are different types indeed, but your solution works!

Comment: Edited the answer to include the actual reason. You're welcome.